# Should I write "Back in her seat" or "Back at her seat" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Without a word to Tom, Mary grabbed the tray with the leftovers of her
>   Smoky Grilled chicken and dumped it into the bin. Back **at/in** her
>   seat, she shouldered her backpack.

Which is the correct option and why? (Or maybe both are correct?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*At* a seat means you are near the seat but not necessarily sitting in the seat.

Did she sit down and then put on her backpack?  Then she did it *in* the seat.

Did she go near her seat, where she left her backpack, and take it and put it on while standing up?  Then she did it *at* the seat.